# How to avoid nested arraylike if statements in python

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, nested

I often find myself coding structures similar to the following:

```py
if x:
    if y:
        #Do thing 0
    else:
        #Do thing 1
else:
    if y:
        #Do thing 2
    else:
        #Do thing 3
```

Sometimes with more levels of nesting, or 3 conditions per variable, etc. I'd like to. clean up the code, so as to not repeat `if y:`. I've thought of creating an array of functions `thing1, thing2` so on, and then indexing with `f[x, y]`, however there is often quite different behaviour, which makes this hard. For example, in a class, `thing1` might use two variables and modify another 2, while `thing2` might do something entirely different with different variables (this makes returning the results in a uniform way hard).

Comment: You can use `and` or `or`.  `if x and y: ...`

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't help: if x and y, if x and not y, if not x and y, if not x and not y, would all be required

Comment: Did you find the solution?